# How to plot bounding boxes within a video frame in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, computer-vision, bounding-box

I have written some code that reads a video file frame-by-frame. Additionally i have read in a csv file call mall-groundtruth.top into matlab using the "csvread" function. Each record contains 12 fields that tag each person in the video, the number of the frame, and the bounding box coordinates of the body.

I would like to plot the body bounding box for a person in each video frame, on top of the video frames.

```
infile= ['mall.avi'];
readerobj=VideoReader(infile);
groundtruth = csvread('mall-groundtruth.top');
for i=1:2:20
  vidframe=read(readerobj,i); 
  imshow(vidframe);               
  drawnow                     
end
```

Comment: It is unclear on what those 12 fields are specifically.  How are the bounding box coordinates stored? Can you give us an example of one row of your CSV?

Comment: You just provided the context but nothing about your question. Please provide the content of the `csv`-file and a mockup of the desired result.